# Slim down large project with many layers to prevent crash in QGIS

Tags: qgis, loading, layertree

I am afraid my project might stop opening at some point because of too many layers and some costly rendering options.

Is there a way to still keep the layers in the layer tree without loading (or even "searching" for) them when opening the project? I am looking for a way to open a project as if it only had, say, 10 layers and some kind of pseudo-layer-tree with some kind of phantom layers that QGIS will only care about when I select them for working on. Would it mayhaps be better to convert my project file from .qgz to .qgs?

The difference to this approach in contrast to the browser in QGIS is that layer settings and options are preserved. The difference in contrast to the current layer tree is that nothing is done with the project layers, not even their file path is checked. This approach is something between the browser state and the current layer tree.

Is my question understandable and if yes, what are the obvious disadvantages to this technique in your opinion?

Comment: If your data is stored in geopackage or spatialite format (maybe other formats too, not sure) then you can embed symbol and label symbology in the data itself so when you add it into the project it will be symbolised correctly automatically. Would that work for you? If not then the only other thing I can think of is temporarily breaking the links to the data.

Comment: Those are very creative suggestions (although, admittedly, the second one is rather destructive than creative, but who makes the difference between the two?). I will inspect these solutions. I would be willing to accept that as an answer since I didn't specify any constraints (and don't intend to do so, now).

Comment: Following @TeddyTedTed solution, for Shapefiles, create a QML of the same name and store in the same folder.

Comment: How many layers are we talking about?